33cm and 2m Antenna separation on a single mast
Hello fellow amateur radio enthusiasts. I have a 10ft mast that I'd like to mount a 33cm and 2m antenna to. The 2m antenna is one of KB9VBRs slim jims - great antenna BTW. Do I need to vertically separate the antennas on the mast? Thanks for the help.

In general: yes. Two antennas that are within each other's near field will not work as they would independently (so, probably much worse). Without having looked up that 2m antenna: do you happen to have radiation patterns (or equivalent data) on your two antennas? https://productfinder.pulseelectronics.com/api/open/part-attachments/datasheet/YA6900W page 8 has an example of how that would look like.

J-poles and similar antennas like slim jims have a null above and below, though - so one J-pole directly above another needs less separation than isotropic radiators would. You'd still want some - the null is only -30 dB or so.

That makes sense. Also its good news! I ended up separating by about 6ft, with the 33cm at the very top and the jpole below.

When antennas like these are close to each other, it changes their radiation pattern and sometimes impedance.  However, it's also possible to take this into account and combine the two antennas into one antenna with one or two feeds.  It's very common to combine jpoles of different bands in either a colinear or side by side mount with the two antennas sharing parts of elements.

Based on some additional research and comments, the answer is that they should  be vertically separated to reduce near-field interference, however, not as much as the entirety of the near field due to the null vertical in the radiation pattern for the slimjim.
Near field is calculated using:
$$
r_{nf} = \frac{2D^2}{\lambda}
$$
Which in this case is going to be larger for the 2m wavelength antenna.
$$
r_{nf} = \frac{2(2 \, \text{m})^2}{2.05 \, \text{m}}
$$
$$
r_{nf} \approx 3.9 \, \text{m}
$$
The radiation pattern of the SlimJim (found here: https://vk8bn.me/info/the-slim-jim-antenna/) features minimal vertical radiation (null).

I decided to separate the antenna by 4 ft. vertically and install a 33cm bandpass filter on the lower power, more sensitive electronics package. The actual setup here is a single mast with a 2m high power transceiver, and a 33cm Meshtastic repeater node.
